# key value not working properly on Processing Android Mode

Tags: java, android, processing

I'm developing an android app through Processing for Android, and I came up with an issue regarding the implementation of a simple text input field.
Basically when I press a key in my Android device (currently using Samsung Keyboard), the `keyPressed()` function isn't called for the previous key until I press the spacebar, and the function is called passing the last non-space character as the `key` value. Because of this, when I type multiple characters (as if I was typing a word) the function is not called at all, until I press the spacebar and the `key` value comes back as an empty space character. I'm thinking the keyboard somehow stores the previous characters in a variable so that it can do its auto-correct/auto-complete stuff and only sends the value to the app when a spacebar or enter key is pressed. Nonetheless processing does not support multiple keys being sent at once and so interprets it as a space character.

Here is the code that reproduces the issue:

```
boolean keyboard = false;
StringBuilder sb;
void setup() {
  sb = new StringBuilder(10);
  fullScreen();
  textFont(createFont("Arial", 40 * displayDensity));
  fill(0);
}    

void draw() {
  background(255);
  text(sb.toString(), width/2, height/2);
}

void keyReleased() {
  background(200, 50, 30); 
  println(keyCode,key);
  if(keyCode == DELETE){
    sb.setLength(Math.max(sb.length() - 1, 0));
  } else {
  sb.append(key);
  }
}

void mousePressed() {
  if (!keyboard) {
    openKeyboard();
    keyboard = true;
  } else {
    closeKeyboard();
    keyboard = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Simple note: It appears that this issue is related specifically to the samsung keyboard. I tested with another one called SimpleKeyboard and it works just fine. But I am still wondering whether there is a way to make this work on the samsumg keyboard.

Comment: I'm still having issues with other latin characters as ñ, á, õ as they  simply dont appear in the key value and dont trigger the keyReleased Event